# Here Android SDK map version

Tags: android, here-api

I am using HERE Android SDK PREMIUM in my application. I am seeing some of the analytical information like map version which I am currently using, sent to HERE server in background from the HERE Android SDK. As part of business restrictions, I would like to know if there is any way I can stop sending these information to HERE server.

Answer (score 0):

Our map services (routing, search, etc) are performed against a version of our maps since we maintain different versions of our maps. From our privacy policy, you are informed accordingly:

> Our applications may contact our servers periodically, for example to check for updates or to send us information relating to service usage.

https://legal.here.com/en-gb/privacy

Please contact HERE Sales team if with your specific requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will contact sales team for further information on this.